# How to fix Windows Update errors?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I have a problem with Windows Update on Windows 10, how can I fix the errors?

I have tools for Distribution Management, and Distribution Maintenance, and System Configuration Compliance Analysis...

Comment: we need to analyze the log files. Copy the folders **C:\windows\logs\CBS** and **C:\windows\logs\DISM** to your desktop, zip them into 1 zip and share the zip via OneDrive share link.

Answer (score 0):

For the Windows Update issue, here are general troubleshoot steps. Please take the following step to have a troubleshoot, if there is any antivirus software installed,please turn them off temporarily to have a check.

1.Run the built-in troubleshoot tool to have a diagnostic :

Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Troubleshooting\All Categories\Windows Update.

2.Clear the windows update cache.

net stop wuauserv

cd %systemroot%\SoftwareDistribution

ren Download Download.old

net start wuauserv

Restart the machine and manually check for updates again

3.Try the fixit tool to reset Windows update Components 
  How do I reset Windows Update components?
  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/971058